# Update Excel ListObject header names without breaking pivots

Tags: excel, vba, user-experience

I have an Excel sheet with a very wide table on it.  Due to developer friendlyness I'd like to use a certain style of column header naming (much like proper Hungarian notation), where I suffix each header name with "column type" tags.  This allows me to easily spot where e.g. apples and oranges are compared.  There are also pivot table reports based on this table.

An example to illustrate this: say you have 2 monetary columns, column A being expressed in another currency than column B.  The model should thus never combine them without first applying appropriate exchange rates.  To spot this I name these columns e.g. `Earned - Cur1` and `Saved - Cur2`.  Any calculation like `=[@[Earned - Cur1]] + [@[Saved - Cur2]]` is illegal, but due to the tags this can be picked up easily in an audit.  I have several such tag groups in use already, and they already prevented some errors creeping in.

However...

The file also needs to be distributed to lots of not-so-savvy end users, and they need to fill in this table and refer to some of the outcome columns.  Most intermediate columns we already hide, but the column names are now far from being user-friendly (like: fill out `Actual - NK/Q1/EC/%`, please?).

And this needs to run in Excel 2010.

What are my options?

**Option 1**
Add an extra row above the table, putting human readable names in there, and just hide the table header row.  This works, but not the users can't sort and filter the table anymore, so that's a no-go.

**Option 2**
Augment option 1 by prepending a newline to each column name, and make the table header row 1 character high.  The header cells would still be there to drive sorting and filtering and the users have human readable names in the row above.  The actual header cells would appear like 'empty' buttons.  Could work, but then the complex formulas become unreadable due to all the newlines from the column names all over the place.

**Option 3**
Add a macro that switches the headers in the table by alternative headers in another row above the table.  The macro should be ran just before sending out the file to the users, and ran again when they return them filled in and all.  I happily coded this option into the file, and it works wonderfully!  But then I realized this (and thus option 2 as well) breaks all the derived pivot tables, since Excel links the data by the names used in the table - update the name, and that section of the pivot will be dropped...

I'd really like the option of having our development-oriented column names in there when we ourselves work with the file, but being able to switch out the headers when needed.  And of course without rebuilding all the pivots after each such switch.

An opening here would be that pivots seem to only drop the columns once they're refreshed.  I could use this to update the header names, then do some magic on the pivots to remap their fields, and only then refresh them, but it seems there's no way from within VBA to accomplish that (`PivotField.SourceName` is read only).

Hopefully someone can think of an alternative, or am I SOL?  I'm totally open to other workarounds.

**Workaround 1**
Insert null-terminating characters in the header names such that they do not show normally in the formulas, but do not show in the table header row.  If only it were that simple though...  Turns out Excel throws up from a `=Char(0)&"abc"`, and things like `=Char(8)&"abc"` (tab anyone?) give Unicode replacement characters when pasted into a header cell... (?)

**Workaround 2**
A last resort seems to be to unzip the excel file, and plough through the xml data to update everything in one go there, then rezip the file.  But this code also needs to be executed by less skilled users, and I see too many ifs and buts to make me feel safe using this setup.

**Workaround 3**
For now I just use a variation on option 2; I have some VBA that 'empties' the header cells instead of prepending a newline to them.  By 'emptying' I mean setting the font size to 1, subscript, non-bold, and then make the font color identical to the background color, followed by setting it's row height to the default 14.5.  The cryptic names do leak out however; column header cell drop down arrows for sorting&filtering show the cryptic name, as well as the pivot field settings and of course the formula bar when you just click such a cell.  But I guess it's the best I can do?

And then again I'm probably just perfectionizing this thing faaar to much :)  But from this point on it's about the challenge!

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Comment: (the key point is the "M" in "MCVE" ("[mcve]") and the fact that you have no code... the goal here is to make it easy for others to help you.)

Comment: You could just give the users a table with friendly names, then copy and paste the data into your own table that runs the pivots when you get it back.

Comment: @Rory: the table is huge, and copy/pasting the data is not really an option (formula columns interspersed with data columns as well).  And the pivots need to be seen by the users while they update the data...

Comment: @ashleedawg: I know this isn't a typical "hey look at this big pile of spaghetti code I copied from Google: please fix it for me" post; I have no actual code to show since everything I can think of can't possibly do what I want it to do.  So sorry, I no MCVE in this case.  It's more of a "what can be done here, if anything at all" instead of a "how do I get this working" post; hopefully it'll tickle the power user's creativity...

Comment: If you need both the original table and the pivot to reflect different names depending on who's using the file, I think you are SOL, other than using code to change the headers and rebuild the pivots.

Comment: When you say "proper Hungarian Notation" please take a look at [Joel on Software](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) and make sure you really mean _Proper_ Hungarian Notation.

Comment: @FreeMan: indeed, I'm not using "n=number, s=string", but more codes for the actual meaning behind the data, like "%" for percentage-as-nr-from-0-to-100 (so we don't forget to /100 when using it), "CA, CB, ..." for the currency set the number is expressed in, "Cor" for the qualifier-corrected version of the same data labelled without "Cor", etc.  If only the rest of the world would catch up on this as well...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you Tick the Box "Add this data to the DataModel" when creating your pivot(s)

AFAIK when your Pivots are connected to the Datamodel instead of directly to the Range/Table you can change your column-names in the Table and your Pivot will stay fine. You could even use other names in your Pivot.

Comment: Oooh, that sounds nice!  And then I couldn't find that option...  Did I tell already that I'm stuck forced to use Excel 2010? :(  Since I have no Excel 2013+ at my disposal either I can't even test if this works, so if anyone else can chime in that'd be great (for future reference).

Comment: Reading a bit more about this it seems you could install the free Microsoft PowerPivot add-in to support data models even in Excel 2010, but then the recipients of this file are all 'noobs' on a corporate network with strict rules on what to install (or rather: what not).  So this seems a dead end in my situation.

Comment: (added the 2010 restraint to the question)